# Cannot access `ARGV` array

Tags: ruby, windows

I cannot access `ARGV` in my installation of Ruby. I am using Ruby 2.2.2 and my operating system is Windows 8.1.

For example, I did an exercise in *Learn Ruby the Hard Way*, which contains this code:

```
PHRASE_FIRST = ARGV [0] == "english"
```

This should create a switch that activates a certain option when I type `"english"` after the file name when I run the file from the command prompt. It does not work.

I used the following code in a file to determine if `ARGV` is empty:

```
if ARGV.empty?
  puts "ARGV is empty."
  exit
end
```

Indeed, it is empty.

I have already set the rbfile appropriately. I used this code, which points to my ruby.exe file:

```
rbfile="C:\ruby22\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*
```

This did not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you run your ruby file?

Comment: `rbfile="C:\ruby22\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*` - if this is ruby code, it's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you refer to rbfile you are talking about the Windows file extension associations?

For rbfile to work, both assoc and ftype must be set up correctly:

```
C:\> assoc .rb
.rb=rbfile

C:\> ftype rbfile
rbfile="C:\ruby22\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*
```

Of course, this isn't necessary to run Ruby programs with arguments. You could always call ruby explicitly:

```
C:\>ruby C:\dev\my_program.rb arg1 arg2
```

, as long as ruby.exe or ruby.bat is in your system PATH.

If things aren't working after confirming assoc and ftype are set up correctly, please provide more details about how you're running your program. It would be interesting to know whether you're running from the command line, directly from a text editor / IDE, or simply double-clicking the file from Windows Explorer.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that because ARGV is empty ar1, arg2, etc. are not processed.

Comment: Yes, I've set up the rbfile and confirmed this. I typically run programs from the command line.

Comment: Yes, I've set up the file file association and confirmed this.

Comment: Have you tried running the program by explicitly executing ruby and passing the program path and arguments?